# Is there anyway to restrict words in <span> tag without changing its display attribute?

Tags: html

As we know, there is a way to restrict words in tag **p**, but I want to do some thing on tag **span** and don't change its display attribute, is there anyway to achieve it?

---

update:
I don't want to change the display attribute, because it can break the normal flow. So, is there any way to achieve it? I think maybe the `text-overflow` just fit to the `block` or `inline-block` box.

[Here is a demo.](http://jsbin.com/katave/1/edit?html,css,output)

Answer (score 1):

Apply the same style that you had on your p tag on the span tag and add this attribute to it:

```
display:inline-block;
```

This will do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

That kind of defeats the purpose of `<span>`, however simply adding `display: block;` or `display:inline-block;` to span gives the same effect. So your code would become:

```css
p,span{
  width: 100px;
  -ms-text-overflow: ellipsis;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
}
span{
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<p>ttestesttestesttestesttestesttestestestest</p>
  <br>
  <span>testesttestesttestesttestesttestesttestesttestest</span>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cdLr6m64/1/)

spans are inline elements by default. Use `display: block;` to override it.